# CFUUIDCreate, iOS version usage statistics and User Permission

Tags: ios, permissions, uuid

I'm considering using the `CFUUIDCreate` API to build a database in my server to measure what percentage of users of each of my apps are running which version of iOS (to help me make a decision on iOS minimum supported version for future development).

My question is: Should I ask the user for permission to send the (**anonymous**) **UUID / iOS version** data pair to my server, or is it OK to do it automatically?

I ask because I could bet on the safe side and ask anyway, but most users would feel intimidated by the technical details and most likely decline. Also, the longer the text in an `UIAlertView`, the more likely the user won't read it.

Will Apple reject my app if I don't ask? Even if they don't, do you think I should always ask the user for permission to send this **anonymous** data?

What's everyone's experience implementing this kind of functionality?

Comment: You can do that automatically, Apple won't reject that. If you want user to be aware of this, then you can add this in terms and condition of app. I had also implemented this in my app.

Comment: Great. And your app was approved, I assume. The Terms and Conditions idea is brillant!

Comment: yeah...my app was approved and in app store from past 6 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is what I'm going to do, based on Nikolai Ruhe's answer but improving on a pitfall I just discovered.

Suppose user John Doe installed my app on his iPhone running iOS 5.0.

On the first launch, the app sends an anonymous request to my server that effectively increases by one the counter for 'Devices running iOS 5.0'. The app records this event and the iOS version (in User Defaults or Keychain) and does not send any further requests as long as the locally stored OS version string and the current one (returned by the system) are equal.

The next week, John upgrades to iOS 5.1 and launches my app. The app detects the OS version discrepancy and sends a new request to my server.

But if this only adds one device to the 'iOS 5.1' population, John's iPhone is now being counted twice: once as "Devices running 5.0" and once as "Devices running 5.1".

So to fix this, my HTTP request should look like this:

```
http://myserver.com/my_stats_scripts/index.php?app_id=com.myCompany.myApp&new_os_ver=5.1&old_os_ver=5.0
```

So my database can **increase** the number of 5.1 devices and **decrease** the number of 5.0 devices by one.

Of course, on the first request, the HTTP parameter `old_os_ver` is set to empty, and the server treats it like a new device.

If I pull this right, I no longer need UUIDs. But I am still sending system info covertly to my server. I think I'll also disclose this on the Terms of Use.

Comment: Perfect! My proposal would count the updates on the device and send the update count along with the request. But your idea is even better because it lets you track exact counts per iOS version.

Comment: Now the only question left is: User Defaults, Keychain or /Caches File?

Comment: ... or KVS (iCloud Key Value Store)? There are good reasons for everything.

Comment: I'd say keychain, because it is per device and survives delete/reinstalls.

Comment: Yeah, I'm inclined to Keychain too. User Defaults and Cache get deleted on reinstall, and I assume not everybody has an iCloud account.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely ask for permission. The crucial bit here is that your data collecting might be anonymous, yet **it can be used it to track individual users**.

Web browsers send a user-agent string with every request. The difference is that they do not send a universally trackable id that would never change.

So the problematic piece in your proposal is the UUID. Why not just leaving it out? Your app would send an anonymous request once and locally store the transmitted iOS version. When the user upgrades the OS, you send another request with the new iOS version and an update count.

Using this scheme you would not transmit trackable data and still get a proper usage-by-os statistic.

Comment: Intersting, send a 'unique request', only once, without UUID. But notice I am using the recommended, non-trackable-accross-apps UUID returned by CFCreateUUID, and **not** the deprecated UIDevice method.

Comment: I understand that the UUID is created by the app. But since it's created **only once** it is possible to use it to track individual users. If your app would send the requests every so often you would be able to track an (anonymous) user's usage of the app. Apple also collects anonymous usage data only after users explicitly opt in.

Comment: Not every so often; only upon installation and OS version upgrade.